# How to pass variadic parameters from one template to another

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I have this code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

template <typename ...Args>
class Button
{
    Button(const std::string& name, Args&& ...args) {
        std::tuple<Args...> tuple_ = std::tuple<Args...>(args...);
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename ...Args>
void addObject(const std::string& name, Args&& ...args) {
    std::unique_ptr<T1> obj(new T1(name, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    //...rest of the code...
}

int main() {
    //if we comment the next line it compiles well
    addObject<Button>("BtnName", 0, 1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it is not compiling with errors like "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol..." or "no matching function for call to 'addObject class Button>(const char [8], int, int, int)'". If we comment "addObject" function it compiles well.

How to pass args to another template in the right way?

Comment: Here `Button` isn’t a type; it’s a template. Since it isn’t itself a type, passing it as a `typename` parameter doesn’t make sense. Does changing the line in `main` to `addObject<Button<int, int int.>>("BtnName", 0, 1, 2);` help? Obviously it isn’t ideal (for that you need to use `template` `template` parameters, which I don’t have the time to write a full answer on now), but if that helps it’ll give you a place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Button` is a class template; when using it in `addObject<Button>("BtnName", 0, 1, 2);`, you have to specify template arguments for it like `Button<...some arguments...>`.

Besides the solution above, maybe you want to move template parameter `Args` from class to the constructor of `Button`, then it could be deduced from the function arguments (i.e. `std::forward<Args>(args)...`).

```
class Button
{
public:
    template <typename ...Args>
    Button(const std::string& name, Args&& ...args) {
        std::tuple<Args...> tuple_ = std::tuple<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RiWi5EVEHZJ2QWW4)

---

Other issues:

- The constructor of `Button` is `private`.
- There's no `#include <string>`.

Comment: Should use std::forward with forwarding references

Answer (score 1):

You can make a template having a template template type parameter so you don't have to specify your args types, as follows

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
template <typename ...Args>
struct Button
{
    Button(const std::string& name, Args&& ...args) {
        auto tuple_ = std::make_tuple<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<template <typename ...Args> typename T1, typename ...Args>
void addObject(const std::string& name, Args&& ...args) {
    auto obj = std::make_unique< T1 <Args...> >(name, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    //...rest of the code...
}

int main() {
    addObject<Button>("BtnName", 0, 1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```